# How to movl $0x41,%ecx

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I've managed 'Hello World' with Gnu as!

So, next thing is print 1 to 10 right? (Maybe in ruby)

At the moment, I'll be happy to print A closely followed by B. Here's what I have.

```
.section .text
  .globl _start

_start:
  # Print A
  movl  $4,%eax
  pushl $0x41
  movl  %esp,%ecx        # Would rather movl $0x41,%ecx
  movl  $1,%ebx
  movl  $1,%edx
  int   $0x80

  # Closely followed by B
  movl  $4,%eax
  incl  (%esp)           # Rather incl(%ecx) here
  movl  %esp,%ecx
  movl  $1,%ebx
  movl  $1,%edx
  int   $0x80

  movl  $1,%eax
  movl  $0,%ebx
  int   $0x80
```

And it actually works, but my question is, why can't I

```
  movl  $0x41,%ecx
```

To begin with, and then

```
  incl (%ecx)
```

a little later on?

Comment: It's not the same. It looks like `ecx` is being used as a base pointer of some sort.

Comment: @Mysticial write is declared as: `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)`, ecx is buf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a sys_write, %ecx wants to point to where the character or characters reside in memory, not "be" the character to print. "incb" might be more correct than "incl" since you're only incrementing one byte - either "(%esp)" or "(%ecx)" ought to work, since they point to the same place at this point. Note that you're incrementing "contents" of memory, not the pointer to memory.

Best,
Frank

Comment: Thanks Frank. That makes a lot of sense.